# Implementing retry logic in node-fetch api call

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-fetch, retry-logic

I hope you will forgive the beginners question, I'm trying to implement a simple retry policy for an api call using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

This is being added to an existing repo using TypeScript so I'm using this also, hence the data definitions.

```
async checkStatus(custId: string,  expectedStatus: string) {
        const response = await fetch(
            `${'env.API_URL'}/api/customer/applications/${custId}`,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: headers,
            },
        )
        expect(response.status, "Response status should be 200").to.be.equal(200)
        const resp = await response.json()
        expect(resp.status).to.contain(expectedStatus)
        return resp.status;
}
```

I am calling it like so

```
await this.checkApplicationStatus(custId, 'NEW')
await this.checkApplicationStatus(custId, 'EXISTING')//and so forth
```

Is there a neat way of retrying based on an unexpected `expectedStatus` ?

Again, I appreciate there may be many examples out there but as a beginner, I am struggling to see a good/best-practice approach so looking for someone to provide an example. I don't need to use Chai assertions, this was just my first attempt.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

you can check a library that I've published [@teneff/with-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@teneff/with-retry)

to use it you'll have to define error classes like these:

```
class UnexpectedStatus extends Error {
  constructor(readonly status: number) {
    super("Unexpected status returned from API");
  }
}

class ResourceNotFound extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super("Resource not found in API");
  }
}
```

and throw respectively depending on the status code:

```
export const getCustomerApplications = async ( custId, headers ) => {
  const result = await fetch(`https://example.com/api/customer/applications/${custId}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers,
  });

  if (result.status === 404) {
    throw new ResourceNotFound();
  } else if (result.status > 200) {
    throw new UnexpectedStatus(result.status);
  }
  return result;
};
```

and then just use the HOF from the library to wrap your function, with options (how many retries should be attempted and for which errors should it be retrying)

```
const retryWhenReourceNotFoundOrUnexpectedStatus = withRetry({
  errors: [UnexpectedStatus, ResourceNotFound],
  maxCalls: 3,
});

const getCustomerApplicationsWithRetry =
  retryWhenReourceNotFoundOrUnexpectedStatus(getCustomerApplications);

const result = await getCustomerApplicationsWithRetry(1234, {
  Authorization: "Bearer mockToken",
});
```

Check this [working setup](https://github.com/so-teneff/so-71705285)